# Set environment variable with zeroes in C

Tags: c, environment-variables

I'm trying to set a environment variable in the shell in C but I'm having a failure because the buffer which contains the data to be stored in the environment variable hax `\x00`s in it. So I was looking for a solution and all of them ended in using `setenv` or `putenv` functions. The problem is both of them stops in the first zero it finds considering it as the end of the string. For example:

```
putenv("SomeVariable=\xAB\xAB\xAB\x00\xAB\xAB\xAB");
```

Won't store the last three \xAB into `SomeVariable`. So I guess the solution to this would be using a function where I can give the initial address of the string and its lenght, such a function exists? Or maybe running some `asm` along the c code to do the job? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the value you want variable to have? How it will look like in the output of env or echo $SomeVariable?

Comment: I want to put a shellcode into it, and it has some `\x00` in it

Comment: Environment variables are C strings. A null byte terminates the value.  You can't change that.  There is no way to embed a null byte in an environment variable; it always marks the end.

Comment: If you truly want a zero then maybe try using `\x30`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer:**
You can't! Use a different format.

**Long answer:**
You can't! byte = 0 is a null terminator: the end of a string.
To get round it you could write it encoded, so write `"\\x00"` instead of `"\x00"` and then write your own conversion routine to change these to bytes afterwards.

Having said that you could use any format you want as long as you don't expect string functions to carry on after the null-terminator!